# I have two versions of my hand retopology. Is it normal to have loops like this? Which one will cause me less problems to UV unwrap?

Tags: modeling, edges, object-mode, retopology

[image]

Here is the first version of the hand retopology. I added more edge loops and changed the edge flow so it could match up with the wrist. Is it normal to have lines that look like this when I use the loop cut tool to check edge flow?
[image]
Hand in object mode. roughly around 35k triangles.
[image]

Second version.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Second hand in object mode. Roughly 30K faces.

Comment: So how I'd describe this is that you have poles-- places where more or fewer than 4 faces meet at a single vertex-- in places that, under deformation, are likely to become highly non-planar.  And, no, under subdivision, that's not good.  Hand topo is a bit difficult because you usually want to be doing some vertex reduction (need more loops to represent fingers than arms).  Here, 2 is better than 1, because 1 has a 6-pole (achtung!  verboten!) in a location that's going to be *highly* non-planar, like 90 degrees non-planar.  But version 2 isn't great either because of those poles at the thumb.

Comment: The issue is not so much UV unwrapping, ( much of a muchness, ) but how the surface will appear when deformed into the shapes you need for your animation.